Is the function $f(x) = m(E \Delta (E+x))$ is continuous with respect to $x$?
Let $m$ be the Lebesgue measure, and $E$ be the measurable set. I'm wondering if the function $$\begin{align*}
f(x) = m(E \Delta (E+x))
\end{align*}$$ is a continuous function with respect to $x$ .
I'm not sure if this is the right statement, but intuitively, I thought this is a correct statement, and I was trying to show this by the following process.
I know that the function constructed in the form $g(x)=m(E \cap (-x,x))$ is a continuous function. This can be shown by using the inequality $\left| m(A)-m(B) \right| \leq m(A \Delta B)$. For this question, I was trying to use the same trick. However, I finally ended up with getting $$\begin{align*}
|f(x+\delta) - f(x)| &\leq  m (E \Delta(E+x+\delta)  \Delta E\Delta(E+x))
\\ &= m((E+x+\delta )\Delta (E+x))
\\ &=  m(E \Delta  (E+\delta) )
\\ &=  f(\delta)
\end{align*}$$ Then I get stuck here. Any help on this? Thanks!

Pretty sue its a duplicate

@Jakobian Can you sent me a relative link for this question?

Not at the moment but from what I remember the function is not necessarily continuous if $E$ has infinite measure, but should be otherwise

I believe this is an exercise in one of Rudin's books

For $f$ to be real valued, you must take $m(E)<\infty$. In that case this is a special case of a theorem in Rudin which says $\int |f(x+h)-f(x)|dx \to 0$ as $ h \to 0$ for any integrable function $f$.
